# Why the file being worked on is not selected in the solution Explorer in VS?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, solution-explorer

For some reason the VS 2008 I have work on, does not automatically select the file in Solution Explorer that I am editing.

Is there any place in option settings where I can turn this feature on?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *want* that feature? It was originally the default in VS2003, but there were so many complaints an option to turn it off was added.

Anyway, you can go into Tools | Options | Projects and Solutions | General and set 'Track Active File in Solution Explorer' to turn it back on.